# Joomla! handling files while developing

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

How should I handle files while developing a module, component, template or plugin for Joomla!

Should I just keep reinstalling them, or can I just edit the files in directly in the Joomla! installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When developing any extension in Joomla, you can simply install it once and from then on, you can edit the installed files.

The only time you ever really need to re-install the extension is if you are trying to execute something upon install, update or uninstall in your **script.php** for testing. For example, if you were to use the following:

https://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Managing_Component_Updates_%28Script.php%29